# Umbraco url for blogs. Adding url prefix

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have a `DocumentType` called `Blogs`. It has a child `DocumentType` called `Blog`.

I create a content of type `Blog`.

The name of that content is "Coding is great".

I can now navigate to that blog with the URL:

> www.example.com/coding-is-great

I want it to be:

> www.example.com/blogs/coding-is-great

How can I prefix URLs with something like the above?

-----**Edited**

In response to wingyip answer. I do already have a structure like this:

[image]

But the urls do not generate as you'd expect.

Comment: Hmmm... the structure above is problematic and non standard.  You could make it work but it would involve mucking around.  The root of your website is usually a parent node under which all of the other pages like About, Contact etc are nested.

Comment: Where is the blogs node going as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with the approach taken by the other two - To achieve what the op requires is simpler by rearranging content.

Its very important to note, and is a common issue with people starting out in Umbraco, that the hierarchy of your document types has nothing to do with the structure/hierarchy of your website.

The structure of your website is dictated by your Content tree.

So if you had a parent node called `Blogs` which had a child node of `Coding is great` then you wouldn't have to do any mucking around - the url would be as you require it.

```
Home
   Blogs
      Coding is great
```

In your document types, is there any reason that `Blog` is a child of `Blogs`. The only valid reason to do this is if `Blog` needs to inherit properties from `Blogs` otherwise `Blog` should not be nested.

If I was doing this I may have a document type called Blog with an associated template that would list my Blog items.

Does that clear anything up?

Comment: How is rearranging the content structure of the site simpler than updating one setting in the web.config file?  And there may be legitimate reasons to have Blogs as the root node instead of a Home node.  However, other than that, your answer is a good and standard solution.

Comment: I agree yes there may be a legitimate reason for using umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath.  However, the wording of the of the post makes me feel that there could be a misunderstanding about the role of document types and their relation to content. I could be wrong... wouldn't be the first time... ;)

Comment: I do not want a Home node for my client to use... This will confuse them, as the home page is nothing to do with the Blogs page... or blogs.

Comment: The solution was to add one root node, I made a Document Type called "Root" and just made a node called "Website"... Then it seems if i add things underneath that, the urls start working again. `Website/News/News-item`

Comment: Marvellous!  Its strange, the first Umbraco site I built was in 2009 and I made exactly the same mistake ie my Home / Root site node was at the same level as all of my internal web pages.  I made things work but had no end of problems and this was all in xslt.

Answer (score 0):

Create in TextPage (Settings=>Document Types=>Master) new property **umbracoUrlAlias** and enter new alias for content
[How create url alias](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYOpUt1BtyM)

Comment: That won't necessarily help - you need to change an appSetting in your web.config file: Change `umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath` from `true` to `false` and re-publish your content.